# How to filter tables while joining in ef?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have 3 tables. Product, Price, and OldPrice which have this relationship:

```
(1)Product-->(*)Prices
(1)Price-->(*)OldPrices
```

I have a method that returns a product with its prices and old prices but I want to filter its prices and old prices while joining. I have written these methods and I am giving these errors:

Method One:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(days));
Product q = (from p in context.Products.Include("Prices.OldPrices").Include("Prices.ClassPartner.SectionPartner.Partner")
where p.ProductId > productId
select new Product
{
Prices = (from pr in p.Prices
    where pr.Enable == true
    select new Price { OldPrices = (from o in pr.OldPrices where o.LastUpdate >= date select new OldPrice { LastUpdate = o.LastUpdate, Cost = o.Cost }).ToList() }).ToList()
}).FirstOrDefault();
return q;
```

Error One:

> The entity or complex type
>   'ComparingSite.Infrastructure.Repository.Product' cannot be
>   constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Then I made a DTO model named ProductDTO like this:

```
public class ProductDTO
{
    public List<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}
```

And Change the method like this:

Method two:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(days));
ProductDTO q = (from p in context.Products.Include("Prices.OldPrices").Include("Prices.ClassPartner.SectionPartner.Partner")
where p.ProductId > productId
select new ProductDTO
{
Prices = (from pr in p.Prices
    where pr.Enable == true
    select new Price { OldPrices = (from o in pr.OldPrices where o.LastUpdate >= date select new OldPrice { LastUpdate = o.LastUpdate, Cost = o.Cost }).ToList() }).ToList()
}).FirstOrDefault();
return new Product {Prices=q.Prices };
```

Error two:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ComparingSite.Model.Prices.Price]
>   ToList[Price](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ComparingSite.Model.Prices.Price])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

So:

How to get a product include its prices and oldprices and filter them while joining in ef?

Thanks.

Comment: you need to use IEnumeable<Price> intead of List<Price> in properties, and remove all inner ToList calls inside query (and by the way, Includes are also useless there).

Answer (score 0):

Why not do that exactly, join and filter ... if you have relationships between tables?
If I understood correctly is this what you need?

```
var prices = (from p in context.Products
             join pr in context.Prices.Include("Prices.OldPrices") on p.ProductId equals pr.ProductId
             join oldPr in context.OldPrices on pr.PriceId equals oldPr.PriceId
             where p.ProductId > productId && pr.Enabled
             && oldPr.LastUpdate >= date
             select pr).ToList(); // here you'll have prices with old prices  

return new Product() { Prices = prices };
```

Comment: Everything is right but just the old prices of the price is coming null.

Comment: Is the Include() parameter right? I think it should be context.Prices.Include("OldPrices") not "Prices.OldPrices" ....